# forecast wunderground api in Swift with json

Tags: json, api, swift, wunderground

I'm trying to get the hourly forecast from the Wunderground API but my code returns this error.
I am interested in the  forecast humidity for a specific hour of the day from the Wunderground API for a research project.

```
  let currenttt       = jsonResult["current_observation"] as NSDictionary
  let currentttv       = currenttt["display_location"] as NSDictionary
  let c: String!      = currentttv["city"] as NSString
```

this code works perfectly on http://api.wunderground.com/api/0c5ad177d8c2e097/conditions/q/CA/San_Francisco.json
but what I need to add in order to obtain the Humidity in different hours.

I am trying to get the information of icon, I understand that it depends of the hour or other value that I need to add in order to get a specific “icon”.

let urlAsString "http://api.wunderground.com/api/0c5ad177d8c2e097/forecast/q/CA/San_Francisco.json"

```
let w       = jsonResult["hourly_forecast"] as NSDictionary
let f       = w["FCTTIME"] as NSDictionary
let a: String!      = f["icon"] as NSString
```

the error is “The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1001.)fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value(lldb) “

and “Thread 10: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT,subcode=0xe7ffdefe)”

Comment: Welcome to SO! What error are you getting? Could you post that together with your question?

Comment: I am trying to get the information of icon, I understand that it depends of the hour or other value that I need to add in order to get a specific “icon”. 

 let urlAsString "http://api.wunderground.com/api/0c5ad177d8c2e097/forecast/q/CA/San_Francisco.json"

let w       = jsonResult["hourly_forecast"] as NSDictionary
let f       = w["FCTTIME"] as NSDictionary
let a: String!      = f["icon"] as NSString

the error is “The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1001.)fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value(lldb)“

Answer (score 0):

```
if let a = f["icon"] { print(a) }  

//prints 'mostly cloudy'
```

No need to cast 'a' as an NSString. String type is inferred.